# javascript-how enable controls of a parent window from child window

Tags: javascript

My requirement is as follows on click of a begin button a popup window opens up and begin button gets disabled. now when the user clicks the "done" button present on the child window
the "begin" button on the parent window should get enabled.

Comment: Please provide more and more detailed information. What do the "begin" and "done" buttons look like? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.opener` to get the parent window, and find the element using `document.getElementById`.

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("yourbuttonid").disabled = false;
```

Comment: @OP: E.g.: `var button = window.opener.document.getElementById('idOfButton');` In the child window, `window.opener` references the `window` object of the parent window. That object has the `document` property that references the parent's document, which of course has `getElementById` and such.

Answer (score 1):

IN PARENT WINDOW DO:

1. disable begin button
2. open the childwindow

IN CHILD WINDOW DO:

```
<input type="submit" value="done" onclick="window.opener.document.getElementById('begin').disabled = false;">
```